# Limit of regular symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've got this statement about the topic. I'm trying to figure it out as it is given without proof.

I know a symmetric matrix is a square matrix $A$ such that $A = A^T$ and a regular matrix is one that only has positive entries.

The statement is as follows:

> If $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ and $A$ is a regular symmetric matrix then $\lim_{m\to\infty} A^m = \frac1nE$, where each entry of $E \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ is equal to $1$.

I've got no problem with limits of regular transition matrices or with limits of other complex matrices. Any insights into the proof of this statement?

Comment: @crash and whoever else approved that edit.  $M \cdot nxn\cdot(R)$ is nonsense and should not have been approved as an edit.

Comment: Guys I'm starting to think this statement is nonsense. If entries all positive, and says nothing about being <1, now if you look at the 2x2 matrix, that is both regular and symmetric. lets call this matrix A. so now with AAA you have exponential powers on the entries. I really dont see how they can then be equal to (1/2). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is false : take$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$
 and diagonalize it in $A=PDP^{-1}$
  with$$D=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}\,\,,\,\, P=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\,\,,\,\, P^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
 Then for all $m>0$
 , we have$$A^{m}=\left(PDP^{-1}\right)^{m}=PDP^{-1}\ldots PDP^{-1}=PD^{m}P^{-1}=P\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 3^{m}
\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}.$$
Now to define the limit operation, we must specify at least a norm (or a metric or a topology) : let us choose for example the norm$$\left\Vert A\right\Vert =\max_{1\leq j\leq n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|a_{ij}\right|.$$
 Then we have$$\left\Vert A^{m}\right\Vert =\left\Vert PD^{m}P^{-1}\right\Vert =\left\Vert \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1+3^{m} & -1+3^{m}\\
-1+3^{m} & 1+3^{m}
\end{bmatrix}\right\Vert =3^{m}$$
 and this does not converge to $\frac{1}{n}$
  when $m\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: I will have a word with my Prof.

Comment: You should indeed, but note here that I have chosen a specific norm. Maybe under other conditions, with a certain norm, it can be true.